# Azure Storage Account - error 403 forbidden

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage-account, sas-token

I have an Azure Function that should process files in a storage account container. The Azure Function should be triggered every day. But once or twice a week I see that some Files in the container are not processed: (At the beginning 401 files from 600 are not processed, because of error 403)

[image]

As I read here in Stackoverflow. It is because of SAS token time skew. Is it possible without a big changing in my code, I solve this problem?

my code:

```
 CloudStorageAccount sa;
 CloudStorageAccount.TryParse("MyConnString", out sa);
 _blobClient = sa.CreateCloudBlobClient();
 ICloudBlob sourceBlob = _blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(new Uri(BlobUrl));
```

**Update**

> Message   Exception while executing function: 
>   process_files_by_http_trigger_activity The remote server returned an
>   error: (403) Forbidden. The remote server returned an error: (403)
>   Forbidden.

Call Stack:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__16.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__13.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35) Inner exception
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException handled at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35:
>   604)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobClient.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35:
>   563)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobClient.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35:
>   546)    at
>   bip.dev.afu.inbound.we.process_xz_files_by_http_trigger.XzFileMove
>   (bip.dev.afu.inbound.we, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null)    at
>   bip.dev.afu.inbound.we.process_xz_files_by_http_trigger+d__10.MoveNext
>   (bip.dev.afu.inbound.we, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__2.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+d__9.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__24.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__23.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__22.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__16.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35) Inner exception
>   System.Net.WebException handled at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync:
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse (System, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b7xxxx934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bfxxxx64e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3xxxxx6ad364e35:
>   677)

Comment: Is it possible that your SAS token got expired?

Comment: I don't think so, because only at the beginning of the process I have this Problem, not at the end

Comment: Can you share how you're creating the SAS Token? Please edit the question and include the code there.

Comment: Actually I use only ConnectionString. I don't generate SAS key. may be SAS is not reason why I get this error

Comment: If you use connection string and if your code is running in Azure, you should not see 403 error because of clock skewness. Do you see full exception details?

Comment: I have updated my post. It would be very nice if you could take a look at it

Comment: Is that you use Azure storage connection string to connect Azure Blob? If so, I think you will not get 403 error

Answer (score 0):

Start with the basics, An Azure Storage connection string uses following format. Please make sure you have provided a right account name and key pair for the connection string. If you set account n1 and account key for account n2, it will cause the exception.

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[accountName];AccountKey=[accountKey];EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

I would suggest you to print you connection string and see if it is the same all the time as you mentioned in the App.setting.

```
Trace.Write(ConnectionString);
```

Please ensure that the current date time of your system/app instance is correct.

The storage services ensure that a request is no older than 15 minutes by the time it reaches the service. This guards against certain security attacks, including replay attacks. When this check fails, the server returns response code 403 (Forbidden).

Hope it helps.Feel free to tag me in your conversation for any additional help.